# Mostrar Cuadro de Diálogo para selecionar un archivo o ruta en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Algunas apps del sistema Android, usan un Cuadro de Diálogo el típico (File Picker Dialog), donde el usuario puede escoger una ruta o archivo, me pregunto ¿cómo se puede llamar ese diálogo?

Estoy mirando la [documentación oficial de google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: relacionada con https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149063/procesar-datos-del-intent-createchooser-modo-multiselector-en-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para llamar el "File Chooser/File picker" Nativo de Android, lo podemos realizar mediante un `intent.createChooser` y obtener el resultado en `onActivityResult`

Para abrir el selector nativo de archivos:

```
private int VALOR_RETORNO = 1;
....
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"), VALOR_RETORNO);
```

Para leer el resultado hacerlo en `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Cancelado por el usuario
    } 
if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == VALOR_RETORNO )) {
    //Procesar el resultado
    Uri uri = data.getData(); //obtener el uri content
}
```

Algunos `Mine types` que he probado para `setType()`

- */* : poder seleccionar todos los archivos
- audio/* : solo seleccionar archivos de audio .mp3,.wav...
- video/* : solo seleccionar archivos de video  .mp4,.avi....
- image/* : solo seleccionar archivos de imágen .jpg,.png....
- text/plain : solo seleccionar archivos con texto plano.

Se pueden concatenar mas de un mine types con el separador `|`.

Con `setType("video/*|image/*");` se establece que sea posible seleccionar tipo de archivos `video` y `image` de la galería.

El primer `minetype` que se especifica tendrá un acceso directo, visible al menu izquierda del selector de archivos.

Comment: Listado de algunos minetypes https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/