# Obtener todos los archivos seleccionados con createChooser en Android

Tags: java, android

Con el intent `Intent.createChooser` muestro el selector nativo para escoger archivo.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "seleccionar fotos"), PICK_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

Proceso el archivo selectionado en `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_CHOOSE_FILE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedUri = data != null ? data.getData() : null;
            }

            break;
        case SOME_OTHER_REQUEST:
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

El problema es cuando especifico que se puede seleccionar más de un archivo con

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);`

Debug de lo que Recibo

> onActivityResult() called with: requestCode = [768], resultCode =
>   [-1], data = [Intent { flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams {
>   mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } clip={image/*
>   U:content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D1332
>   ...} }]

¿Cómo se puede obtener el listado de uris que hacen referencia a los archivos?

Comment: Necesitas recogerlas mediante el uso de `Clip Data`. [Mira aquí un ejempo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336150/5587982).

Comment: he encontrado eso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773100/can-it-is-possible-to-allow-user-for-multiple-selection-of-file-in-storage-acces